# Why is it called specific gravity, when it defines the ratio of densities?

Tags: terminology, dimensional-analysis

I recently learned about the term "specific gravity" and was surprised to see nothing in the definition that relates to gravity, or indeed, any sort of force.

I'm sure there's a historical reason for this, but I'm unable to find an answer.

To be clear, my question is why the word "gravity" exists in this definition, which, as I understand, is simply the density of something relative to a reference density (e.g. of water at a certain temperature).

Comment: *Specific gravity* is simply a confusing and obsolete term.

Comment: BTW, there's a Stack dedicated to the history of science & mathematics. They don't appear to have a question on the history of the term "specific gravity". https://hsm.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22specific+gravity%22 But there is a question on mass vs weight https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/11896/were-the-kilogram-the-grave-etc-meant-to-be-units-of-weight-units-of-mass-o

Comment: oh that's interesting, perhaps this question would be better suited for that stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct (and more meaningful) term is *relative density*.

It measures the ratio of two densities, where one is a reference one (usually water). So the specific gravity (SG) of a substance $x$ with respect to water is
$$SG=\rho_x / \rho_{water}$$

**Why specific?**

Specific means "per unit volume". Because the mass of an object is given by

$$M_x=\rho_x V_x$$ if you take *the same volume* $V$ of the substance $x$ and of water and you weight (measure the mass) the ratio is going to be

$$M_x/M_{water}= \rho_x V / \rho_{water} V= \rho_x / \rho_{water}$$

Usually specific means that the quantity does not depend on *how much* you consider, if you take 1 L of ethanol or 2 liters - they have the same SG because you need to compare it with *the same amont* of water and the volume goes away in the ratio.

**Why gravity**

Because, as you saw before, it is related to mass i.e. to gravity in a way (when you measure a mass on a scale you are actually measuring its gravitational force). To measure the SG you need to either weigh a fixed volume of of $x$ and compare its weight to the same amount of your reference substance (water in our case) as we did before. But you can also find the volume $V_x$ at which the weight of $x$ equals a given volume of (e.g.) water.

Indeed, you can measure it by putting the two amounts on a scale (the one with a lever and two things to be weighted at the same tme, old style) and see when the scale measures the same mass. When that happens, because you now know the volume at which the masses equal each other you can write
$$M_x=M_{water}$$ which means
$$\rho_xV_x =\rho_{w}V_{w}$$
i.e.
$$SG=\rho_x/ \rho_w=V_w/V_x$$
so you can extract the specific gravity by measuring things on a scale i.e. weighing them i.e. using gravity.

(Of course, as we said before, you can choose *any* reference volume of water: this will result in a different volume of $x$ *but* the ratio will be independent of the volume)

Other options are: immerse your substance in water and see if it sinks.
Or use one of the many instruments described on wikipedia (: most of them however relate on gravity as a way of measuring the SG.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. This idea of using gravity as a tool to measure density ratios (by virtue of the ability of gravity to measure density ratios by balancing a scale) adds some substance to the inclusion of the term "gravity" in the definition, though I agree that it removes from the precision of the term.

Answer (score 0):

Relative density is a better name that is in common use.

"Specific" usually means per unit mass in thermodynamics nomenclature; for example specific volume or specific internal energy.  However, for "specific gravity" I think "specific" means per unit volume.  "Weight" typically means how heavy an object is on earth; specifically $mg$ where $m$ is mass and $g$ is the acceleration of gravity on earth.  So "specific gravity" refers to the relative weight of a unit volume of a substance (relative to water) which is proportional to its density.

Comment: I thought specific gravity refers to the mass of a unit volume (relative to to the mass of the same volume of water), not weight. 
If weight were at issue here, then surely the gravitational force experienced on the surface of the earth would be included in the reference conditions, yet it is not.

Comment: I think in the past whoever came up with this poor name "specific gravity" was thinking mass "is" weight since on earth weight = mg and g is constant (ignoring small change in g with latitude due to earth's rotation).  That is why I think "gravity" was used in the name.  Just a reasonable guess on my part.

Comment: Yea, that was my thought, and may well be the case. Seems unusually sloppy though!